# Publishing Meteor Application on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, meteor

im trying to publish an application to heroku. I have tried this for many days and looked online for help but to no avail. Would greatly appreciate any help. I usually run the app locally by running meteor --settings settings.json

[image]

```
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644749+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644745+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/meteor.js:78:4
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644747+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/meteor.js:1438:3
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644750+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644752+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644759+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644761+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.run (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
2018-07-22T06:56:43.644762+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
2018-07-22T07:15:39.976102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zera.herokuapp.com request_id=e3d0a4be-37bd-4fdc-bcc5-746639370eda fwd="202.156.97.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-22T07:15:40.752510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zera.herokuapp.com request_id=ace7e44d-741d-4d29-92b0-a92bc8560c8c fwd="202.156.97.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here are my configuration variables

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much for your help and I appreciate any advice.

Comment: What Heroku build pack do you use?

Comment: I have solved it with ghybs help. Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is `MONGO_URL` instead of `MONGODB_URI`.
- Copy-paste the *content* of your `settings.json` file into the value of your `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable, or use Heroku CLI to assign it (in which case you can use the `cat` tool in your command).

Comment: You are a real life saver. Thank you so much for your help and have a good day :)